# Что будет, если истечет время токена? Как пользователю выдать новый токен?

Tags: сервер, backend, token

юзеру нужно будет обязательно заново авторизоваться? Или сервер может выдать каким-то образом новый токен? Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: если токен истек, то вы для себя решите для начала, вы все еще ему доверяете или уже нет ? Если решили что доверяете - то вопрос, зачем вообще у токена время. А так конечно вы можете предусмотреть в API метод для обмена истекших токенов и клиент должен будет периодически их вызывать ...

Comment: Только начинаю разбираться в token/cookie и еще не все понятно) Например, все говорят, что id пользователя нельзя передавать, но по моим ощущениям, что токен, что id злоумышленик получит то, что хочет

Comment: получив чужой токен конечно злоумышленник получит что хочет. но вот увидя, что передается только id, злоумышленник может просто изменить его на другой и станет другим пользователем ... Единственное назначение токена - что бы его нельзя было подделать, прикинувшись кем то другим.

Comment: А если id из 30 рандомних символов, как он узнает, что там за id у других?

Comment: В принципе этого конечно было бы достаточно. Но предположим, злоумышленник украл таки этот id у другого пользователя. Пользователь это обнаружил и поменял свой пароль. Но id от этого не изменился и злоумышленник может продолжать пользоваться. А вот все выданные токены при смене пароля отзываются (удаляются и т.п.) что бы перестали действовать.

Comment: Да, я как раз таки и пришел к такой мысли, что, если изменить данные для входа, злоумышленнику будет без различно, ибо он шлет по id и это смерть для системы)

Comment: А вот, где лучше всего хранить этот токен? Я вот в vk чистил и cookie и localStorage, а из аккаунта все равно не выходит.

Comment: ну обычно все таки в куках, если сайт расчитан на перезарос страницы при каждом обращении. Вы после очистки браузер перезапускали ? А то ведь он может храниться вообще в переменной в JS-коде на странице. кстати, с чем то работающим через api это обычное дело, потому что в этом случае страница не перегружаеться каждый раз, а js делает api запросы и токен передает вообще обычным параметром запроса

Comment: Перезагрузка действительно помогла, спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 0):

> Что будет, если истечет время токена?

То, что будет запрограммировано вами.

> Как пользователю выдать новый токен?

Как и старый. Устаревший токен есть отсутствие оного.